# Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow not able to track feature points across frames

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

I've found the feature points on the initial frame using the Shi-Tomasi `goodFeaturesToTrack()`. But the issue is that `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` is not able to consistently track the feature points across the frames.

Here are the feature points detected on the initial frame: [Frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLB9M.jpg)

And here's the optical flow of the second frame: [Frame 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOQqj.jpg)

As you can see the feature points on the vehicles are completely off. Here's [Frame 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P6VU.jpg) and [Frame 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQOMD.jpg) for further reference.

And no, it's not an error in my code in plotting the feature points. When I run the same code but do it on the masks of the vehicle, it works fine. [Frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzSpT.png), [Frame 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RT53.png), [Frame 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0bp9.png), [Frame 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsp2o.png). Some feature points change because the contour of the mask keeps changing, but apart from that, the optical flow of the feature points across the frames is fairly consistent.

```
def optical_flow(img_list):
    # Parameters for ShiTomasi corner detection
    feature_params = dict(maxCorners=200, qualityLevel=0.4, minDistance=7, blockSize=7)

    # Parameters for Lucas Kanade optical flow
    lk_params = dict(
        winSize=(15, 15),
        maxLevel=2,
        criteria=(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03),
    )

    # Create random colors
    color = np.random.randint(0, 255, (300, 3))

    # Take first frame and find corners in it
    old_frame = img_list[0]
    old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    box = bb_list[0][0]
    p1x = int(box[0])
    p1y = int(box[1])
    p2x = int(box[2])
    p2y = int(box[3])

    roi = old_gray[p1y:p2y, p1x:p2x]
    roi = cv2.resize(roi, None, fx= 2, fy= 2, interpolation= cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(roi, mask=None, **feature_params)
    

    for point in p0:
        x, y = point.ravel()
        cv2.circle(roi,(x, y),4,(0,0,255), -1)
    
    cv2.imshow("frame", roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


    print(p0)
    p0 = scale_p0(p0)
    print(p0)
    p0 = bb_offset(p0, box)
    
    old_vis = old_frame.copy()
    for point in p0:
        x, y = point.ravel()
        cv2.circle(old_vis,(x, y),4,(0,0,255), -1)
    
    cv2.imshow("frame", old_vis)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    
    # Create a mask image for drawing purposes
    mask = np.zeros_like(old_frame)

    optical_flow_orientation_list = []
    j = int(0)
    for frame, boxes, labels, scores in zip(img_list[1:], bb_list[1:], labels_list[1:], scores_list[1:]):
        # Read new frame
        frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        #visualize_bb(boxes, labels, scores, frame)

        # Calculate Optical Flow
        p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
            old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params
        )
        # Select good points
        good_new = p1[st == 1]
        good_old = p0[st == 1]

        # Draw the tracks
        for i, (new, old) in enumerate(zip(good_new, good_old)):
            a, b = new.ravel()
            c, d = old.ravel()
            optical_flow_orientation_list.append(calculate_perspective(a, b, c, d))
        
        # finding the outlier optical flow vectors
        is_outlier_list = is_outlier(np.array(optical_flow_orientation_list))
        
        for i, (is_true, new, old) in enumerate(zip(is_outlier_list, good_new, good_old)):
            a, b = new.ravel()
            c, d = old.ravel()
            if not is_true:
                mask = cv2.line(mask, (a, b), (c, d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
                frame = cv2.circle(frame, (a, b), 5, color[i].tolist(), -1)

        # Display the demo
        img = cv2.add(frame, mask)
        cv2.imshow("frame", img)
        #k = cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF
        k = cv2.waitKey(0)
        if k == 27:
            break
        
        j += 1
        # Update the previous frame and previous points
        old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
        p0 = good_new.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
```

Here's the optical flow function that I've written. I'm finding the feature points inside the bounding box region and then finding optical flow. I'm only keeping track of those optical flow vectors whose orientation is within a certain threshold of the median of the optical flow vector orientations.

Comment: For me it looks like thst there are several features tracked correctly (e.g. a cluster close to the vehicle ground). What exactly do you expect?

Comment: @Micka as you can see that in the initial frame that cluster of features was on the wheel. But from the second frame and onwards they kind of fall back

Comment: can you draw the features of the 2nd frame? can you try to increase the max-corners value?

Comment: @Micka Increasing the max-corners value didn't change much. I've detected the features on the second frame and it looks correct. https://imgur.com/a/2YH031f

Comment: can you try to play with maxLevel and winSize parameters? It could even be possible that optical flow isnt suited for that kind of objects/scenes/content

Comment: @Micka thank you it worked! The feature points now stick to the vehicle. But now there's one other issue, the feature points on the pavement are getting stuck to the vehicle when the car is moving over them. I did some trial and error with the parameters but the problem is I don't really understand how they affect the algorithm. I read this post: https://justinshenk.github.io/posts/2018/04/optical-flow/ It said a smaller window size makes the features stick to the objects, but I had to increase it to (35, 35) instead

Comment: I guess winSize is basically how many much area around the feature is used to match it to the other image. This might be one weakness of the algorithm that you have to have a fixed winSize. You could try scale-invariant keypoints instead, like SIFT or ORB. You will find tutorials and sample code online.

Comment: @Micka thank you. I was actually thinking about using ORB before I got your help. I was thinking about finding keypoints in two consecutive frames, finding the best matches, and manually draw a straight line between the pixel coordinates

Comment: yes, that could work better. If you observe that ORB doesnt work try SIFT as well. Afaik since 2021 it isnt patented anymore (if that's important for you) and maybe part of general opencv lib (not the nonfree module anymore?)